# UWSGI Stack Dump

Tags: python, linux, django, uwsgi

Is it possible to take UWSGI stack dump in Linux.

If yes how can i do that?

Also the purpose is to investigate CPU spikes,

please help me as i am very new to open source

TIA

Answer (score 0):

kill -USR2 pid

where pid is the process id of the worker you are interested in

(i suppose you mean the c stacktrace, if you want the python one check there: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Tracebacker.html)

Comment: Thanks I will have a look, but i want to understand something
I have a service in django-uwsgi and we are getting CPU spikes, how can i go ahead with the investigation and what are the counters should i look for. If i get some guidance it will be helpful